# Как получить fileList через request.files flask

Tags: reactjs, flask

Как получить fileList через request.files flask

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@app.route('/files', methods=['POST'])
def get_files():
    files = request.files.getlist("images")
    print(files)
    return ''
```

Код возращает пустой массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код React:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/array')
            .then(({ data }) => console.log(data))
    }, [])
    
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    // const formRef = useRef();

    const handleFile = (e) => {
        setFiles(e.target.files);
        console.log(e.target.files);
    };

    const sendFiles = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // let formData = new FormData(formRef.current);
        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('images', files);

        axios.post('/files', formData, {headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}})
            .then(({data}) => console.log(data))
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {/* <form ref={formRef}> */}
                <input
                    type="file"
                    // name="images"
                    multiple="multiple"
                    onChange={e => handleFile(e)}
                />

                <input type="submit" onClick={sendFiles} value="Отправить файлы" />
            {/* </form> */}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Код api.py

```
@app.route('/files', methods=['POST'])
def get_files():
    files = request.form['images']
    print(files)
    # files = request.files.getlist('images')
    # print(files)
    return '123'
```

Comment: Если вы отправили не файлы, а строку со значением `[object FileList]`, значит нужно смотреть не `request.files`, а `request.form`. Ну а если вы всё-таки хотите отправить файлы, значит в javascript-коде нужно отправлять именно файлы, а не строку

Comment: @andreymal, Здравствуйте, я отправляю файлы: https://pastenow.ru/4186eaaddd0d3884b50ed82953f6f54a,
но в request.form строка получается: https://pastenow.ru/e8d0dcc2c1850623d66dfe41278b20a8. Мог бы я прикрепить код, а вы бы не подсказали как лучше в моём случае лучше сделать, был бы очень благодарен

Comment: @andreymal, мне нужно работать с этими файлами, а именно обработать каждый, в принципе закомментированный код работает, но я не хочу форму использовать, или fileList и request.form не то что мне нужно?

Comment: Метод `formData.append` поддерживает добавление только строк, Blob и File, а вы пытаетесь в него запихнуть массив (а точнее, объект FileList). Так как вы запихиваете неподдерживаемый объект — он автоматически преобразуется в строку вида `[object FileList]`. Добавляйте файлы поштучно в цикле, не пытайтесь добавлять весь массив целиком за раз

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо большое

Comment: @andreymal, здравствуйте, не подскажите можно ли из контроллера вернуть на клиент массив картинок?